# Cleaner way to write ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code is as follows :

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
import { filter_names } from './filterActions';
import Price from './price';
import Year from './year';
import Make from './make';
import Model from './model';
import Mileage from './mileage';
import Transmission from './transmission';
import Fuel from './fuel';

class filters extends React.Component {

    showFilters(filters){

        return filters.map(filter => {
            switch (filter.name){
                case filter_names.priceRange:
                    return <Price recap={filters.some(f => f.name === filter_names.priceRange)} title="Price" filters={filters} {...this.props}/>;
                case filter_names.year:
                    return <Year recap={filters.some(f => f.name === filter_names.year)} title="Year" filters={filters} {...this.props}/>;
                case filter_names.mileage:
                    return <Mileage recap={filters.some(f => f.name === filter_names.mileage)} title="Mileage" filters={filters} {...this.props}/>;
                case filter_names.fuel:
                    return <Fuel recap={filters.some(f => f.name === filter_names.fuel)} title="Fuel" filters={filters} {...this.props}/>;
                case filter_names.transmission:
                    return <Transmission recap={filters.some(f => f.name === filter_names.transmission)} title="Transmission" filters={filters} {...this.props}/>;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        })
    }


    render(){
        const language = this.props.language;
        const filters = this.props.filters;

        return (
            <div className="filters noPadding col-xl-8 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={500} transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
                    {this.showFilters(filters)}
                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default filters;
```

Is there any way to write it on a cleaner way? I have in showFilter function all those components. Do I need to repeat it for every component or is there any simpler way to do it?

Comment: I think you should either be more specific about what you are trying to achieve, or then this should be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

Create a base class for the filter:

```
class BaseFilter extends React.Component {
    showFilters(filters){       
    }
}
```

Derive all your filter classes from BaseFilter:

```
class AnotherFilter extends BaseFilter {
  render() {
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve their problem (plus, using inheritance in React is usually a bad idea). They don't want every component to have access to `showFilters`, they want to show a different set of child components based on the result of that function.

Comment: react prefers composition over inheritance. Inheritance won't simplify the code, only hide it in a subclass

Comment: i got the question wrong! I was under the impression that there were lot of Filter components which had some common method. I have encountered some scenarios where base class makes sense.